# Kickstart installation: Unable to read package metadata

Tags: linux, redhat, kickstart

I'm trying to install a CentOS OS with kickstart using HTTP as the installation source.
The kickstart server and the installed server are both running on VMs on the same machine.
after the anaconda system installer starts it fails with the following message:

[image]

I tried installing two different versions of Centos(5.5 and 5.2), and they both pass a CDROM media test the manual installation provides.

The only errors on the kickstart server side are some errors in the httpd log I consider irrelevant:

```
[Sat Mar 12 23:25:19 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.112] File does not exist: /tftpboot/linux-install/platforms/CentOS5.5/images/product.img
[Sat Mar 12 23:25:19 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.112] File does not exist: /tftpboot/linux-install/platforms/CentOS5.5/disc1
```

I tried searching the internet for days and haven't found any solution...

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score -1):

You need to [mount each CD](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-steps-network-installs-x86.html#id4021789) on your webserver and [enter the URL](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-begininstall-http-x86.html) to the directory containing them.

Let's assume *example.com* has a document root of the directory */var/www/html/*, you want to make the installation material available at *http://example.com/centos5/*. and you have the installation images in */var/isos*. On your webserver you would run

```
mkdir -p /var/www/html/centos5/disk1
mount -o loop /var/isos/disk1.iso /var/www/html/centos5/disk1/
```

to set up the first disk. You would repeat that for other disks, just changing the number.

Now you could boot a machine with `linux askmethod`. When asked for the installation method, you would choose *http*, specify a web site name of *example.com*, and a CentOS directory of */centos5/*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can verify from expereince that this does work. It is also described by Red Hat in my second link. To quote their documentation: "You can save disk space by using the ISO images you have already copied to the server. To accomplish this, install Red Hat Enterprise Linux using ISO images without copying them into a single tree by loopback mounting them. For each ISO image:
mkdir discX;
mount -o loop RHEL5-discX.iso discX 
Replace X with the corresponding disc number."